# How to display the_post_thumbnail if a post has one or otherwise display the first image in a post?

Tags: functions, loop, post-thumbnails, conditional-content

I would like to create a condition that checks to see if a post has a thumbail and if it does display it, otherwise display the first image in a post.

I tried something like this in my loop.php but it didn't seem to work:

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(640,320)); ?></a>
<?php } else { ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo catch_that_image(); ?>" /></a>
<?php } ?>
```

This goes in my functions.php file:

```
<?php
    function catch_that_image() {
        global $post, $posts;
        $first_img = '';
        ob_start();
        ob_end_clean();
        $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
        $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

        // no image found display default image instead
        if(empty($first_img)){
             $first_img = get_bloginfo('template_url')."/images/no_image.gif";
        }
            return $first_img;
    }

    $imgURL = catch_that_image();
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

[Get the Image](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/get-the-image/) does what you need and better. It's NOT overwhelming with lots of unnecessary features, and does what it says. Try it to see if it does what you need.

> **How does Get the Image plugin pull images?**
>
> - Looks for an image by custom field (one of your choosing).
> - If no image is added by custom field, check for an image using the_post_thumbnail() (WP 2.9's new image feature).
> - If no image is found, it grabs an image attached to your post.
> - If no image is attached, it can extract an image from your post content (off by default).
> - If no image is found at this point, it will default to an image you set (not set by default).

Comment: I installed this plugin and activated it. I don't understand how I can configure it. It doesn't work on my site..

Comment: @Matt Justin Tadlock's plugins come with a `readme.html` file, follow the instructions in it. Never seen an updated plugin by Justin that didn't work (so to say). :)

Comment: +1 for Justin's plugin, wonderfully written one!

Comment: @brasofilo - with the Get the Image plugin, am I able to change the order (priority) in which it checks for images?

Comment: @Matt Why is that a problem? Are you not using a caching plugin? If you are not, you have more serious problems to deal with, than this neat code. The plugin does the checks in a very sensible manner.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it, I'm using it and it's super easy and simple, just paste this into your `functions.php`:

```php
function autoset_featured() {
    global $post;
    $already_has_thumb = has_post_thumbnail($post->ID);
    if (!$already_has_thumb) {
        $attached_image = get_children( 
            "post_parent=$post->ID&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&numberposts=1" 
        );
        if ($attached_image) {
            foreach ($attached_image as $attachment_id => $attachment) {
                set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, $attachment_id);// the size of the thumbnail is defined in a function above
            }
        }
    }
}  //end function

add_action('the_post', 'autoset_featured');
add_action('save_post', 'autoset_featured');
add_action('draft_to_publish', 'autoset_featured');
add_action('new_to_publish', 'autoset_featured');
add_action('pending_to_publish', 'autoset_featured');
add_action('future_to_publish', 'autoset_featured');
```